# docker sh при первой загрузки

Tags: docker, sh, dockerfile

Здравствуйте подскажите  как выполнить скрипт после того как запустился контейнер, у меня не создается симлинк

```
FROM mynick/test:v1.2
RUN a2enmod rewrite
COPY start.sh /usr/sbin/start.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/sbin/start.sh
RUN sed -i -e 's/\r$//' /usr/sbin/start.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/sbin/start.sh"]
CMD [ "/usr/sbin/apachectl","-DFOREGROUND"]
```

```
#!/bin/sh

ln -s /usr/share/redmine/public /var/www/html/redmine
rm /var/www/html/index.html
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`ENTRYPOINT` и `CMD` взаимоисключающие команды, нельзя их иметь одновременно.

Перемести `/usr/sbin/apachect -DFOREGROUND` внутрь `start.sh` (вместо `exit 0`)